# AlpineJS transition: fade out text, replace text and then fade in new text

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I am working with the TALL architecture (TailwindCSS + AlpineJS + Laravel + Livewire) in a project and I want to achieve the transition specified in the question title:

1. Fade out old text
2. Replace text
3. Finally fade in new text

My best try so far:

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div x-data="{ formMode: 'create' }">
  <div x-show="formMode == 'create'" class="px-4 sm:px-0"
       x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-300"
       x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 transform scale-90"
       x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 transform scale-100"
       x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-300"
       x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 transform scale-100"
       x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 transform scale-90">

      <h3 class="text-lg font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">
          Create new project
      </h3>
  </div>

  <div x-show="formMode == 'update'" class="px-4 sm:px-0"
       x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-300"
       x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 transform scale-90"
       x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 transform scale-100"
       x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-300"
       x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 transform scale-100"
       x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 transform scale-90">

       <h3 class="text-lg font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">
           Update project details
       </h3>
  </div>
  
  <button @click="formMode = 'update'" type="button" 
          class="items-center px-2.5 py-1.5 text-xs font-medium rounded shadow-sm text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700">
    Toggle text
  </button>
  
</div>
```

This actually fades out text, replaces it and fades in the new one based on `formMode` variable in AlpineJS but the problem is that I am working with 2 different divs + h3, and thus there is an **undesired overlap when both elements are transitioning**, losing the visual effect.

Any ideas on how could it be done using only one div + h3?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want a cross-fade, for sure one element has to overlap another, thus you'll likely make use of `position:absolute`, `z-index`, etc. As well, it means both elements are visible at the same time. If you don't care about cross-fade and/or can't do layering, you'll have to wait for the first animation to complete before showing the next element. For that you need to know when the animation finishes, so you'll need logic for that.

Comment: On a side note, if using purely CSS animations and using the convenient [transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event) event, Alpine seems to have problems with this. For animations, I don't even consider Alpine.